# Respaldo parcial de base de datos

Tags: sql-server

necesito crear un respaldo parcial de una base de datos SQL Server(solo algunas tablas); por ejemplo si la tabla tiene integridad referencial debo de restaurar las tablas que componen esa integridad(tablas padres, y tablas hijas), espero alguien pueda darme alguna sugerencia llevo días con esto, estoy muerto. Gracias

Comment: Entonces, digamos que tienes 10 tablas, y solo quieres respaldar 3, pero como 2 de esas tres apuntan a 3 de las otras, tendrias que respaldar 6 en total? No me queda muy claro tu pregunta

Comment: y que probaste? y como queres hacerlo? usas una herramienta externa o las de SQL server? donde lo quieres respaldar?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Puedes poner esas tablas dentro de un mismo Filegroup y hacer respaldo sobre a este último. Te comparto la documentación oficial al respecto:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-files-and-filegroups-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Puedes poner esas tablas dentro de un mismo Filegroup y hacer respaldo sobre a este último. No puedes realizar respaldos sobre una transacción en particular.

Para crear el filgroup en una base de datos, ejecuta el siguiente script:

```
Use master
go
alter database MyDB add filegroup [NewFileGroupName]
go
```

Creas una tabla nueva con este FileGroup

```
create table MiTabla (Columna1 int, Columna2 date) on NewFileGroupName
```

Luego para ejecutar le respaldo:

```
backup database MyDB Filegroup = N'NewFileGroupName' to disk = N'Ruta\archivo.bak' with notformat, noinit, name = N'Filegroupbackup', skip, norewind, nounload,  stats = 10
```

Es importante que la base de datos en cuestión esté en modo de recuperacción **Full**